# Exclude files which are still being written on in IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path).Length

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a Filesystemwatcher to track progress of a Directorycopy to a USB Stick with a progressbar. here is my code:

```
Public counterLocalFiles As String
Private Sub CopyUSB
        fsw_USB = New IO.FileSystemWatcher(Path)
        fsw_USB.IncludeSubdirectories = True
        fsw_USB.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        UpdateProgressBarMaximum2(CInt(counterLocalFiles))
        counterLocalFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, 
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(SourcePath, Path)"*.jpg*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length    
End Sub

Private Sub fsw_USB_Created(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles fsw_USB.Created
        Dim counterUSBFiles = IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
        UpdateProgressBar2(CInt(counterUSBFiles))
        UpdateLabelText2(CStr(counterUSBFiles) & " von " & CStr(counterLocalFiles))
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgressBarMaximum2(Maximum As Int32)
    If ProgressBar2.InvokeRequired Then
        ProgressBar2.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf UpdateProgressBarMaximum2), Maximum)
    Else
        'We are on the UI thread so update the control.
        ProgressBar2.Maximum = Maximum
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgressBar2(Value As Int32)
    If ProgressBar2.InvokeRequired Then
        ProgressBar2.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf UpdateProgressBar2), Value)
    Else
        'We are on the UI thread so update the control.
        ProgressBar2.Value = Value
    End If
End Sub
```

My Problem now is that, I use a USB 2.0 Stick which is kind of slow. Now the Directory copy actually creates all the files first ( I guess its some sort of multithreated copy) and then writes to them. The SystemFileWatcher fires regardless of the Size of the files and the counter goes up. So by the time The progressBar is full, we are still a long way to go from actually being finished with the copy to the usb-drive. Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Instead of subscribing to the created event, subscribe to the changed event. You'll get multiple of these. When the size reaches the expected size then increment your progress.

Comment: and how do i determine when that point is reached?

Comment: You could create a dictionary of filename vs filesize first. But on second thoughts I'd cheat. Set the progress bar to filecount + 1 spaces, then as each file change event with a size > 0 happens I'd add the filename to a hashset and set the progress bar to the hashset size. So for a 1 file copy, there'd be 2 slots, slot one will be filled as soon as data arrives in the file, then the progress bar would close when the file copy if complete.

Comment: There's no way to know unless you know the file size in advance. You could try to open the file to see if it's in use. I had to parse files on a server once. To know if they were done, I would save the size and if the size didn't change after x amount of time, I would assume the file wasn't touched anymore. That was good for that project, might not work for other.

Comment: Maybe i approach the problem in a wrong way, is there a more easy way to get a progress bar like this? For example, the file copy event is synchronous from as far as I know, so basicly if i do a for each file method and copy every file one by one, it should not behave like this and start all files at once? Or does anyone else has a different approach to it?